# Material-ui - nested menu - change css width of menuItems[] of a menuItem

Tags: css, material-ui

```
<Menu desktop={true} autoWidth={false} style={{width: "120px",  overflowX: 'hidden'}}>
  <MenuItem desktop={true} rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />} primaryText="Option1" menuItems={[
    <MenuItem desktop={true} primaryText="Option1a" onTouchTap={props.ontheclick}/>,
    <MenuItem desktop={true} primaryText="Option1b" onTouchTap={props.ontheclick}/>]}/>
  <MenuItem onTouchTap={props.ontheclick} primaryText="Option 2" />
</Menu>
```

I have a material ui menu like above. I want to set style like I'm doing in `Menu` for MenuItems in `menuItems={[MenuItem, MenuItem]}`. I've tried adding `style={{width: "120px",  overflowX: 'hidden'}}` to `<MenuItem desktop={true} primaryText="Option1a"/>` but it doesn't change the actual width of the nested menu. Right now, my main menu is way thinner than my nested menu. How to do this?

Comment: You need to make your question (wall of code) simpler and more generic.

Comment: I tried adding style={{width: "120px"}} to the nested MenuItem, it works for me. I am using material-ui v0.19.0.